# Skrollr changes height of body

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I have a problem with my site. I am using Skrollr to display one image and a text on this image. The text fades out and the image has some nice effect. First I used Foundations as a framework, but this doesn't work for me. So I switched to Bootstrap. Now I have the issue that my body height is set to 2157px. I don't know why, but on pages without Skrollr this doesn't occur. For me it seems like Skrollr is the problem. I used the following code:

```
<section id="slide-1" class="homeSlide">
    <div class="bcg"
        data-0="background-position: 0px 0px;"
        data-300="background-position:0px -200px;"
    >
    <div class="hsContainer">
        <div class="hsContent container"
            data-0="opacity:1;"    
            data-500="opacity:0;"
        >
            Lorem ipsum
        </div>
    </div>
</div></section>
```

My Css is:

```
.hsContainer {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    opacity: 1;
}

.hsContent {
    font-size:5vw;
    max-width: 450px;
    margin: -150px auto 0 auto;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #ebebeb;
    padding: 13% 8%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #333;
}

.bcg {
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 45vw;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I don't see, where the problem comes from. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is skrollr that is causing that issue as an effect of its parallax calculations. [You can pass in `forceHeight=false` as an option](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr#forceheighttrue) when you initialize skrollr, like so:

```
var s = skrollr.init({
  forceHeight: false
});
```

And it will then leave your `<body>` height alone.